# Chessdoku Level 0 (trial)

Tags: chess, sudoku

Welcome to Chessdoku! It's like Sudoku but chess! This is level 0, so it's a trial run and will be fairly simple to solve (level 1 has been posted [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107343/chessdoku-level-1-beginner)). This puzzle is just for the concept. Here you have a grid of knights and queens:

[image: chessdoku grid]

Your goal is to get one knight and one queen each in 8 of the 9 3x3 squares.

Here are the general rules of Chessdoku:

- Assume standard legal chess movements.
- No capturing pieces.
- Kings do not have special rules (e.g., check or checkmate).
- Each piece may only be moved once.

---

*Note: This is a test run to see how this type of puzzle will be received. I know it's easy, but please don't judge it based on difficulty; future puzzles (if this one is well-received) will be more complex and difficult).*

Comment: Does each piece have to be moved?

Comment: Nice concept! Looking forward to the next one in the series (and to your next puzzles in general, since it seems like you've taken a break in the last few months :))

Comment: @hexomino -- Nope, that's not required.

Comment: @LukasRotter -- Thanks! It's true, I was away for a while but I hope to be more active with these puzzles.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath when I read this before, I thought it was cheesedoku :/ .

Comment: This looks fun!

Comment: @Anonymous -- That would be interesting! :):)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Credit to Lukas Rotter in the comments who corrected some mistakes I had.

Assuming we don't have to move all the pieces, here is one way to do it

> Move all the knights first according to the diagram below, in any order.
>  Then move the top middle queen. Then move the rest of the queens according to the diagram, in any order.
>  [image]

Comment: Isn't the top middle queen blocked by the unmoved knight?

Comment: Damn, sniped. I actually have essentially the exact same answer as you, except with slightly different knight positions.

Comment: @LukasRotter D'oh! Thanks, fixed now

Comment: Also, the left middle queen would have to move before the right middle knight :)

Comment: @LukasRotter For such a straightforward question, I've really messed this up. Thanks again!

Comment: Looks right to me! Nice job! :):)

Comment: I retitled this to Level 0 and created a new Level 1 [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107343/chessdoku-level-1-beginner). See what you can do with it!