# Chessdoku Level 1 (beginner)

Tags: chess, sudoku

I just tested out a new type of puzzle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107339/chessdoku-level-0-trial) (sorry if there's any confusion with the titling) called Chessdoku! Welcome to level 1. Here's the grid:

[image: chessdoku grid]

Your goal is to get one black and one white piece each in 7 of the 9 3x3 squares.

Here are the general rules of Chessdoku:

- Assume standard legal chess movements.
- No capturing pieces.
- Kings do not have special rules (e.g., check or checkmate).
- Each piece may only be moved once.

Comment: I'm not sure [sudoku] is even relevant here - the only thing related to Sudoku is the fact that you have a 9×9 board divided into 3×3 subboards.

Comment: @Deusovi -- I would argue that it remains relevant because the general structure/format remains very similar (one of each type in each block of 3x3 and, of course, the 9x9 -> 3x3 division you mentioned).

Comment: But it's *not* one of each type in each block - it's *at most* one of each type, because you can leave some empty. And the row/column rule is entirely gone too. So it seems to me that very little is left of the Sudoku ruleset other than visual similarities - it's *much* more like [Satogaeri](http://www.cross-plus-a.com/html/cros7stgr.htm). (And it seems to me that if you made the puzzles unique so the solutions were logically deducible, this could be an interesting Satogaeri variant!)

Comment: I don't think it's worth an edit war, because the tag *is* applicable to some extent. But I'd recommend thinking about whether the Sudoku similarity is *really* the core of what you're doing here. I think you could make some more interesting puzzles if you dropped that constraint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

> I completely overlooked that theres an obvious way to not move the white queen at all. Just switch the target boxes of the top right/middle black queens. But I am too lazy to edit all of it now :)

As a GIF:

> [image]

As a picture

> Moves are in the order red, green, blue, purple
>  [image]

The final formation being

> [image]

Comment: Nice job! Certainly starting off simple, but we're building up. :):)